# Is "library catalogue" uncountable?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Oxford Dictionary provides a sample phrase:
•to consult the library catalogue

Why not library catalogues?

Answer (score 2):

You mean '**Is** it uncountable?'

As a former library cataloguer, I can tell you that each library has *one* catalogue (a list of all the books and other media it contains). The information used to be on cards filed in alphabetical order; nowadays they are normally online. When you 'consult the library catalogue', you look in the catalogue of the library you are in to see whether the book you want is available there.

You would 'consult library catalogues' if you were searching the online catalogues of several different libraries.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and I edited it to "Is" now. I am learning the correct grammar now especially my plural problems and it would help me a lot as people correct my grammar. But I found a sample sentence in Cambrige dictionary: Students can search the library’s online catalog and order books. So does this online catalog also mean one catalogue book? Thank you.

Comment: As I said in my answer, library catalogues are now usually online. "The library's catalog[ue]" is the list of that library's resources. Catalogues are seldom in book form, because they are constantly changing as old stock is discarded and new stock acquired.